# Creating an image datastore from the images already loaded in the memory

Tags: image, matlab, datastore

I was working with the [The Street View House Numbers (SVHN) Dataset](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/) and primarily with the `train_32x32.mat` file given. Loading the file as:

```
load train_32x32.mat
```

loads 2 variables `X` and `y` in the workspace.

The dimensions of each `X` and `y` are `32 x 32 x 3 x 73257` and `73257 x 1` respectively. I am used to creating an `imageDatastore` and then using `augmentedImageDatastore` to put some form of pre-processing before attempting to create a `CNN`.

But now since `X` already contains the image pixels for `73257` images, is there a way I could still create an `imageDatastore`? For what I could make through the [documentation of imageDatstore](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.imagedatastore.html), it only accepts the physical location of the image directory.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a way unless I save them to disk files first.

May be I could then delete those files when my program exits.